# first order liner / separable differential equation: $x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - y = -x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the title says, please help solve:  $x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} - y = -x$

Here are the instructions:

Using the method for 1st order linear equations. Which of these is also separable? Solve these using the separation of variables method.

Thanks.

Comment: Divide through by $x$ and then the equation will be separable by using the substitution $z=\frac{y}{x}$

Comment: @George1811 please explain step by step?

Comment: If the answer helped, you could consider accepting it :) You could also use integrating factors to find the correct answer.

Comment: I am not very good at this :P, what other factors are there? Im struggling to understand still

Comment: Integrating factors is the name for an alternative method used to solve linear first order equations. The answer I outlined below is just as valid though.

Answer (score 1):

Well dividing through by $x$ gives $$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}=-1$$
Use the substitution $z=\frac{y}{x}$ and rearrange for $y=zx$.

Now differentiate this expression with respect to x giving, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=z+x\frac{dz}{dx}$$
Sub this into the above equation:
$$z+x\frac{dz}{dx}=-1+z$$
Now $$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{-1}{x}$$
Solve this now separable equation to find $z$ in terms of $x$ then sub $z=\frac{y}{x}$ back in to get $y$ in terms of $x$.